# How to get size of WPF user control as its executing a storyboard animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a user control that is animation and growing in size over 15 seconds.  When a user clicks it, I am trying to determine the size of it at that moment.  ActualWidth/Height always returns the size of the full control before any animation.

Comment: Are you animating Width & Height, or are you doing a RenderTransform?

Comment: Try calling the Measure() and Arrange() of your usercontrol before retrieving the ActualHeight/Width.